# Caja uses 100% of the CPU

Tags: caja

When I start the system Caja uses 100% of the CPU and every time I have to kill it.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I do not know exactly your problem. But on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 I have problem with thumbnail generation. I disabled them from Caja (Edit|Preferences, Preview, Other Previewable Files, Show thumbnails -> Never). Then re-enabled them (Edit|Preferences, Preview, Other Previewable Files, Show thumbnails -> Local Files Only). See [bug 1676013](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1676013).